# Ensuring const safety

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Is there a way to ensure const safety when dealing with constant data?

I mean, is there a way to prevent this kind of code?

```
const int a;
int* p = (int*)&a;
*p = 0;
```

Comment: You can´t prevent casts. Or: You should not cast const away until you are 100% sure what you´re doing.

Comment: You can't prevent it but you can possibly detect it with compiler warnings or static analysis tools. For example in GCC there is `-Wcast-qual` which should warn you about it.

Comment: Set yourself a coding standard to not use casts, then you will avoid this happening by accident.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to prevent the kind of code that you are showing. The cast re-interprets the pointer, letting the caller do whatever he pleases. As the result, the program gets undefined behavior, and may crash. Unfortunately, it will not *always* crash, and on some platforms it will never crash.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's the point of a cast.

Consts are hints to the programmer more than the compiler and they're free to be ignored if the programmer wishes. Adjusting that data may cause major problems if the compiler has made the data resident in a read-only part of memory, for instance.

You can't avoid someone adjusting the data, even if const were "enforced". e.g.:

```
int* p
const int a = 2;
int b;

p = &b + 1;
*p = 0;
```

This may destroy the value of `a` -- it depends on the platform and compiler. (i.e. which way the stack grows and where it places `a`, `p` and `b` in relation to each other).

Sometimes you may *want* to cast a const pointer to a non-const pointer -- i.e. to pass the parameter to free() if the free() call is not in the exact same scope as the malloc() one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int const* make_array(size_t size)
{
    int *p = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    memset(p, 0xAA, size * sizeof(int));

    return p;
}


int main()
{
        int const *cp = make_array(500);

        //do lots of read-only things with cp

        free((void*)cp);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still not a case where most people would do this. Usually it would be regular pointer in main, which doesn't do much work, and the pointer would passed on to other functions as a `const char*` argument. One would separate code into functions that work on the data, and don't change it, and a other functions that also write it. I would never do such cast in such every day scenario as this one.

Answer (score 0):

the const qualifier itself doesn't prevent that, but you can supply others with a copy of your data. Also, developers almost never use such cast, as it can crash the code in runtime. The compiler usually assumes the data pointed to by the const qualified pointer is not changed, even by code outside this compilation unit. So if some people start using such casts, their programs might start crashing, if they use on optimizing compiler. Probably you will never meet such practice in your work, so don't worry about it.